# Video screen is stretched vertically

Tags: android

I am working in android. I am using VideoView. Its stretched vertically when orientation is Portrait mode.

This is my xml:-

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/lineartop"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="-5dip"
    android:background="@drawable/tab" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fileNametitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20dip" />
</RelativeLayout>


<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/VedioFooter"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lineartop" />

<include android:id="@+id/VedioFooter"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    layout="@layout/bottom_layout_without_full_window_button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

please suggest me what should i do to show my video correctly in Portrait mode also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this problem.

THis is my new code :-

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/lineartop"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="-5dip"
    android:background="@drawable/tab" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fileNametitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20dip" />
</RelativeLayout>


 <LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <VideoView
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/videoId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

   </LinearLayout>


    <include android:id="@+id/VedioFooter"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    layout="@layout/bottom_layout_without_full_window_button" />
```